# LaTeX editor with live preview for Windows and RTL language support?

Tags: editors, windows, preview, wysiwyg

Looking for a LaTeX editor for Windows with the following features:

- Live preview. (Inherited live preview, not something achievable if you do some tricks.)
- RTL language support. (Hebrew for example)
- Auto-complete LaTeX keywords. (Like in [LED](http://www.latexeditor.org/))

Googled and browsed other questions here, on SO and on [tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com). All I find is either only for mac or have no live preview.

Can someone please point one app that support all the features stated above?

Comment: FYI [Comparison of TeX editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) with [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and see if it it works for you.

I've been using it for some Hebrew with good results, although on a Mac. Yet there is a Windows version available as far as I know.

Live preview is unfortunately not available but if you configure it with your PDF viewer it works smoothly. It does have a automatic build feature which equates to Eclipse compiling the PDF upon every save. So you just press `ctrl+s`, double click the pdf file in Eclipse and it shows the latest version.

Comment: Great, it has all I need, and with the [Pdf4Eclipse](http://borisvl.github.com/Pdf4Eclipse/) plugin it is almost like a live preview. Which encoding have you used for Hebrew?

Comment: I'm using this XeTeX example [http://en.foursenses.net/hebrewinxetex](http://en.foursenses.net/hebrewinxetex) as my base. The Pdf4Eclipse renders some characters a bit funny in Eclipse, although opening the same PDF in another viewer shows it to be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

The best LaTeX editors for that platform are Texnicenter, Texmaker and Texworks. The first two are far more complete, but provide no live-preview (neither does the latter, anyway). They provide code-completion and project support as well many other feature.

The only editors which give you a sort of live preview are [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) and [Gummi](https://gummi.app). LyX is also available for Windows, while Gummi is just a Linux project. I don't know if these also provide RTL support though.

Comment: Regarding `Gummi`, they [are currently developing a Windows port](http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/?p=322). It is, however, unfinished yet.

Comment: IMHO LyX should really not be called a "LaTeX editor". LyX is a **text system in its own respect** (with many nice concepts, though) that employs an **own file format**. LaTeX is "just" the backend LyX uses to achieve great typesetting. However, it is not interoperable with other tools on the level of LaTeX source code.

Comment: The features requested are not that interoperable too. The user who asked this question has _not asked for a general purpose LaTeX editor_, but a fairly specific one with particular features. So I didn't care that much about how to call LyX, I just thought _it was one of the best choices for the issue he proposed_.

@diabonas my fault, I didn't see that news.

Comment: @MarcelloMassaro: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll check for RTL support and update.

Comment: Please be aware that Texniccenter 1 RC 1 which is the latest stable release in Oct 2010 does not support UTF-8