# How can I see what am I writing in a TeX editor?

Tags: editors, preview, wysiwyg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to get real-time compilation for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633/is-there-any-way-to-get-real-time-compilation-for-latex)
>   [What's the fastest way to preview changes as I learn TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16914/whats-the-fastest-way-to-preview-changes-as-i-learn-tex)

I am new member on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) and I am surprised  that I can automatically see math formulas and symbols that I am writing there. When I am writing a long formula or an equation in a TeX editor (TeXMaker), it is difficult to understand some things. Is it possible to use this kind of preview in an editor, and not only on the website?

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16914/whats-the-fastest-way-to-preview-changes-as-i-learn-tex) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633/is-there-any-way-to-get-real-time-compilation-for-latex)

Comment: Other related questions: [LaTeX editor with live preview for Windows and RTL language support?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32273/latex-editor-with-live-preview-for-windows-and-rtl-language-support), [Getting a live preview of TeX (on Windows) - for just a small snippet of code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34522/getting-a-live-preview-of-tex-on-windows-for-just-a-small-snippet-of-code), [Live tex compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21746/live-tex-compilation)

Comment: Specifically for LaTeX equations, consider using the online equation editor: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php