# Free, "compile and preview as you type" latex editor

Tags: editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to get real-time compilation for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633/is-there-any-way-to-get-real-time-compilation-for-latex)
>   [How can I see what am I writing in a TeX editor?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38927/how-can-i-see-what-am-i-writing-in-a-tex-editor)

I've seen some websites, such as ones on the stack exchange, that are able to interpret and display latex code as you type.  I'm curious if there are any freeware latex editors that can do that same thing... That is, compile and display in real time as the latex code is added.  This will be very helpful to me to detect my errors earlier on rather than waiting until i've written a lot of code and then debug it.

Comment: [gummi](http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi), [bakoma](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/), etc?

Comment: You could always just compile regularly; there is no reason to wait until you have written a lot of code.

Comment: The technology used on the network is [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), which interprets only a subset of TeX-like math notation. The overhead for that is much less than for completely typesetting a full LaTeX document.

Comment: MathJax is a javascript library running on a web browser to render TeX (other than TikZ and PSTricks) stuffs. Among others, [gummi](http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi), [bakoma](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/) are TeX editors that also work with TikZ and PSTricks.

Comment: @IanThompson: True, but that gets cumbersome when you're writting a lot of equations.

Comment: @Paul Your title asks for WYSIWYG, but the body of the question seems to be more about a rapid preview (compile after each keystroke or similar). Perhaps you could clarify what you are after?

Comment: @JosephWright: I see what you mean.  I think I was actually referring to rapid preview (compile with each stroke).

Comment: @Paul I created an app for Android,
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TeXEditor.TeXEditor_full

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there exists only one real WYSIWIG editor http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/win32/microimp/microimp.pdf, which was the first and last try to create one for LaTeX. In general: it is not possible to have a WYSIWIG editor! A user can overwrite anything of the existing code or define anything new. This makes it nearly impossible to write such an editor.

What you can have is an editor which runs in the background ???latex when the source code changes. But this implies two windows, input and output, like Gummi does: http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi

Answer (score 2):

Emacs with preview-latex does what you are looking for: http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex.html.

I've tried it and works but I don't like all the auxiliary files it needs to generate, so I tend to just "compile early compile often" :)

Comment: no, it shows only parts of the document, eg math stuff, in a preview

Answer (score 1):

You also have something similar in the [TeXMacs](http://www.texmacs.org/)-project. It will give you TeX-quality output, and a pretty true WYSIWYG input.

I have never used it myself.

Comment: as far as I know it is not a (La)TeX editor. It uses it's own file format and , of course, some facilities from TeX